# Microsoft Graph for reading my own calendar in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am not an expert on all things Azure, but I'd like to read my own calendar programmatically. I found some code to access Microsoft Graph and read my calendar, but it seems I have to create an App Registration first, is it possible to SKIP the app registration if I only need to read my **OWN** calendar? here's my starting point:

```
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var userName = "myaccount@company.com";
var password = "pwdhere";

var userNamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
    userName, password, tenantId, clientId, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes);   

var events = await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Events
    .Request()
    .Filter("startsWith(subject,'All')")
    .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an app registration, otherwise you couldn't even log in. If it's an Azure AD you don't control, such as your employer, you'll need to get an admin to create that for you.

Comment: it seems a bit ridiculous that I need an app registration to programmatically read my OWN calendar, but that's how it is, thanks!